# Cumulative total in power bi dax without date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have to get a cumulative running total of one column (value will be 1 or 0), but need to do it by another numeric column with values such as 0,1,2,3…etc.  except this numeric column also has blanks (when the first column is 0, the numeric column will be blank).  I need the cumulative total of the first column by these numeric values of 1,2,3,4,etc. I’ve tried so many variations and googling and nothing seems to work…I even tried ChatGPT and still wasn’t getting the right result, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I follow, but ... I created a sort of "time/date" table with just a series of numbers from 0 to my last day number. {0,1,2,3..} and then I joined that to the fact table (daynumber, Count).
Then my measure is like this:

```
RT Count = CALCULATE(SUM('QtyFact'[Qty]),
             FILTER(
                 ALL('DimDays'),
            'DimDays'[TheDay]<=MAX('DimDays'[TheDay])
))
```